# MySQL wildcard return only matches with hyphen and number

Tags: php, mysql

In my database I have the following rows which will increment if it's a duplicate:

foo 
 
foo-1 
foo-2 
foo-3 
f
f-1 
f-2
f-3
bar
bar-1

I want to query the db and get the **last f-#**. I've tried using the LIKE operator below:

```
SELECT * FROM links WHERE slug LIKE '$slug%' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1";
```

**My Problem**
If $slug == f it returns foo-3 rather than f-3. Is there a better way to use the % wildcard?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM links
WHERE slug LIKE '$slug-%' OR slug = '$slug'
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The alternative, if you didn't want to do an `OR`, would be to use a `REGEXP` match. However, you might give up the ability to use an index for the query if you do that.

Comment: Yes. Used your recommendation above, which didn't work until I removed the hyphen in '$slug-%'.